# How to get the last read activity time stamp of mnesia

Tags: event-handling, erlang, mnesia

Is there any mechanism to get informed about the last activity performed on a mnesia datababse, inparticular, the timestamp?
my case is not restricted in write activities but I need to know the last read activity.

Thank you very much.

Comment: There is no mechanism I know to get the last READ activity, but from your question it seems like you need to know the last timestamp of more than READ. I'm guessing you know about the the event handling capability (http://erlang.org/doc/apps/mnesia/Mnesia_chap5.html#event_handling) which allows one to be notified concerning Write, Updates and Deletes. 

So, if you had a gen_server (or some other type of process) that was subscribed to those events, could you wrap a Read in a function that sends a message to the very same gen_server?

Comment: Yes, actually it is more like a timestamp. So what i do is using a gen_server and update a timestamp in its State.

Answer (score 1):

Mnesia is not general purpose database, it's more like a library. So, no, there is no such functionality. But you can implement it by yourself. Just create proxy module for mnesia and update timestamp each time any function from your module get called. Also, notice, since Erlang is concurrent and parallel there might be cases where different functions called simultaneously. So, before updating timestamp make sure it's value bigger than one that's already stored.